# url rewriting -- the url rewriting code giving "Object not found!" error

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect my website links

1, the original link is

- www.website.com/products.php?id=abcd12345

2, the browser will see

- www.website.com/products/abcd12345-something1-something2.html

so i want to redirect second link request to first link -- but now my present code giving  "Object not found!" error

below is my code in .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^(.*)products/([A-Za-z0-9]+)(.*) $1/products.php?id=$2  [NC,L]
```

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: the second link contains  something1-something2 can be continue as may..... like something1-something2-something3-something4 etc

Comment: What's the `$1` doing there? Are you trying to match something before `products/`? If not, remove `$1/` (including the slash) and it should work.

Comment: wow....thanks....... now its working fine....butt new problem occured its note loading the css and images

Comment: That is to be expected if your assets are located under `products/` too. You could prepend a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to exclude those files or change your [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to only rewrite requests for `.html` files: `RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9]+).*\.html$ products.php?id=$1  [NC,L]`

Comment: no its still note working..     but now i managed to change the rule as        www.website.com/something1-something2-abcd12345.html         i re located the product id to the end of the link and changed the cods as         RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ products.php?id=$1 [NC,L]     can you please confirm if there is any potential danger in my code